# python program that downloads options data using IBKR

Tags: python, pyalgotrade

So I have written the following program:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

import threading
import time


class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:
            print('The current ask price is: ', price)

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

#Create contract object
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = 'TSLA'
contract.secType = 'OPT'
contract.exchange = 'SMART'
contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = '2023120'
contract.strike = 100
contract.right = 'C'
contract.multiplier = '100'


#Request Market Data
app.reqMktData(1, contract, '', False, False, [])

time.sleep(9) #Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data
app.disconnect()
```

The output I get is

```
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
ERROR -1 2158 Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefnj
```

As you can see there is no price of the option, I looked at the interactive brokers API guide I changed the code a bit but still no price came

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

import threading
import time


class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickOptionComputation(self, reqId, tickType, tickAttrib, impliedVol, delta, optPrice, pvDividend, gamma, vega, theta, undPrice):
             super().tickOptionComputation(reqId, tickType, tickAttrib, impliedVol, delta,
                                          optPrice, pvDividend, gamma, vega, theta, undPrice)
             print("TickOptionComputation. TickerId:", reqId, "TickType:", tickType, "TickAttrib:", (tickAttrib), "ImpliedVolatility:", (impliedVol), "Delta:", (delta), "OptionPrice:", (optPrice), "pvDividend:", (pvDividend), "Gamma: ", (gamma), "Vega:", (vega), "Theta:", (theta), "UnderlyingPrice:", (undPrice))

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

#Create contract object
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = 'TSLA'
contract.secType = 'OPT'
contract.exchange = 'SMART'
contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = '2023120'
contract.strike = 100
contract.right = 'C'
contract.multiplier = '100'


#Request Market Data
app.reqMktData(1, contract, '', False, False, [])

time.sleep(9) #Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data
app.disconnect()
```

Output

```
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
ERROR -1 2158 Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefnj
```

I really don't know what I am getting wrong but it is probably in my calculation of the option price I have followed the API calculation guide ( https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/option_computations.html#opt_calculations) in the second edition of the code, So I still don't know.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Thank you for your time!

I wanted to download options data using python from IBKR it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases that use `self.nextValidOrderId` variable and before call `app.run` set `app.nextorderId = None` that should be defined by:

```
def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
    super().nextValidId(orderId)
    self.nextorderId = orderId
```

now after initialize `api_thread`

```
api_thread.start() 
while True:
    if isinstance(app.nextorderId, int):
        print('connected') 
        break
    else:
        print('waiting for connection')
        time.sleep(1)
```

it will print:

```
...
waiting for connection
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
ERROR -1 2158 Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefnj
...
...
...
connected
```

By this way i see that is used `Order` instances and `app.placeOrder` method, and maybe it is not what you desire. This script wraps `tickOptionComputation` and use multithreading to create a infinite loop to connect to the api, the difference to the above code is that you need to modify it to manage a `while` loop to print a *connection status* otherwise you also should check on Settings section for any improperly stablished feature that generates connection issues.

```py
from ibapi import wrapper
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.utils import iswrapper
from ibapi.common import *
from ibapi.contract import *
from ibapi.ticktype import * 

import threading
import time

class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, app, threadId):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadId = threadId
      self.app = app

   def run(self): 
      self.app.run() 

class TestApp(wrapper.EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        wrapper.EWrapper.__init__(self)
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self) 
        self.nextValidOrderId = 0 

@iswrapper
def nextValidId(self, orderId:int): 
    print("setting nextValidOrderId:", orderId)
    self.nextValidOrderId = orderId  
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = 'TSLA'
    contract.secType = 'OPT'
    contract.exchange = 'SMART'
    contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = '2023120'
    contract.strike = 100
    contract.right = 'C'
    contract.multiplier = '100'
    self.reqMktData(1, contract, "", False, [])

@iswrapper
def error(self, reqId:TickerId, errorCode:int, errorString:str):
    print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString) 

@iswrapper 
def tickOptionComputation(self, reqId, tickType, tickAttrib, impliedVol, delta, optPrice, pvDividend, gamma, vega, theta, undPrice):
    super().tickOptionComputation(reqId, tickType, tickAttrib, impliedVol, delta,
                                  optPrice, pvDividend, gamma, vega, theta, undPrice)
    print("TickOptionComputation. TickerId:", reqId, "TickType:", tickType, "TickAttrib:", (tickAttrib), "ImpliedVolatility:", (impliedVol), "Delta:", (delta), "OptionPrice:", (optPrice), "pvDividend:", (pvDividend), "Gamma: ", (gamma), "Vega:", (vega), "Theta:", (theta), "UnderlyingPrice:", (undPrice))
```

```
app = TestApp()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, clientId=123)
print("serverVersion:%s connectionTime:%s" % (app.serverVersion(),
                                            app.twsConnectionTime()))

threadApp = myThread(app, 1) 
threadApp.start()  
  
time.sleep(9) #Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data
app.disconnect()
```

additional info:

- [Warning messages code](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/message_codes.html) (2104, 2106, 2158)

  > ... *This is a notification and not a true error condition, and is expected on first establishing connection.*
- [Tick Types](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/tick_types.html)